# Criar template para rotas no Laravel com resource

Tags: laravel

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um template no blade contendo as ações genéricas(exibir,editar,apagar) para todas as rotas de minha aplicação, por exemplo na coluna de ações tenho o código:

```
<td>
  <!-- botão Exibir -->
    <a href="{{ route('admin.cores.show',[$cor->id]) }}" class="@lang('global.button.fields.exibir')">@lang('global.app_show')
    </a>
  <!-- botão Editar -->
    <a href="{{ route('admin.cores.edit',[$cor->id]) }}" class="@lang('global.button.fields.editar')">@lang('global.app_edit')
    </a>
   <!-- botão Apagar -->
    {!! Form::open(array(
        'style' => 'display: inline-block;',
        'method' => 'DELETE',
        'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans("global.app_are_you_sure")."');",
        'route' => ['admin.cores.destroy', $cor->id])) !!}
    {!! Form::submit(trans('global.app_delete'), array('class' => trans('global.button.fields.apagar'))) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</td>
```

A rota da view:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

    //Usuários e Permissões
    Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UsersController');
    Route::post('users_mass_destroy', ['uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@massDestroy', 'as' => 'users.mass_destroy']);
});
```

Minha ideia seria criar um template único para os botões e evitar ficar repetindo códigos e poder controlar as diretivas em apenas um arquivo.

Por exemplo, criar um arquivo acoesTemplate.blade.php com as seguintes linhas:

```
  <a href="{{ route($routeKey.'.show', $row->id) }}" class="@lang('global.button.fields.exibir')">@lang('global.app_show')</a>
  <a href="{{ route($routeKey.'.edit', $row->id) }}" class="@lang('global.button.fields.editar')">@lang('global.app_edit')</a>
    {!! Form::open(array(
        'style' => 'display: inline-block;',
        'method' => 'DELETE',
        'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans("global.app_are_you_sure")."');",
        'route' => [$routeKey.'.destroy', $row->id])) !!}
    {!! Form::submit(trans('global.app_delete'), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

E depois apenas chamar esse arquivo nas colunas de exibição, porém não sei como implementar as variáveis nas rotas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que seja mais ou menos isso que você quer:

```
<!--Esse é um exemplo do blade dos botões-->
<a href="#"  id='showBTN' class="btn btn-success openmodal" 
title="Visualizar">
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</a>

<a href="{{route( $rota.'.edit' , $id)}}" class="btn btn-primary"      title="Editar">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Uma blade importa o arquivo acima passando a id (ou qualquer informação que deseje):

```
 @include('cadastro.template.acoesBTN', array('id'=>$p->id))
```

E por fim o método do seu controller que trata a rota referente aquela view

```
public function index(Produtor $produtor)
{       
    $produtores = $produtor->all();
    $rota = 'cadastro.produtor';
    return view('cadastro.view.produtorView',
        compact('produtores', 'rota'));
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, economizou muita repetição de código assim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um botao.blade.php

e depois importar no seu código, terá que alterar os href pegando a url local desenvolvendo uma nomenclatura única.

Não te recomendo fazer isso, por que todas as tuas variáveis terão o mesmo nome para funcionar.